# How to use the verb give and the verb make?

Tags: grammar

There are many verbs take two objects, one of them is the verb give.
He gives me an advice.
Also the verb make.
But when I note the verb make I found.
He makes me happy. (I mean no two object), only one object and adjective.
Can you explain please?

Comment: No article with the non-count noun "advice",  "He gives me advice".... Why do you think "make" can have two objects?  (it can, but you don't explain how you know this)

Answer (score 1):

The majority of verbs are transitive- they require a subject and an object. A smaller number do not require an object- they are intransitive. An even smaller number of verbs are ditransitive- they can take a direct object and an indirect object. The indirect object can alternatively be attached to a transitive verb form with a preposition to give the same meaning. There are several other verb forms that can each be used with just a handful of verbs.

Many verbs have more than one meaning, with some meanings having different verb forms: here are examples with **[give](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/give)**

> Please give generously - *intransitive, with adverb*
>   He gives to several charities - *intransitive, with preposition*
>   This machine gives change - *transitive*
>   He gave a book to me - *transitive, with preposition*
>   He gave me a book - *ditransitive*

Note that, with ditransitive verbs, the order of the objects is reversed compared to the transitive with preposition version. The preposition is normally **to**, but for some words it is **for**...

> He made a cake for me - *transitive, with preposition*
>   He made me a cake - *ditransitive*

Make has meanings that are intransitive, transitive and ditransitive: in addition, it is one of the small group of words that can take a NOUN + ADJECTIVE. Examples are [make](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make) (CAUSE TO BE), [consider](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consider) (OPINION), [go](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go) (BECOME) and [go](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go) (BE) which can take an object followed by an [object complement](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/object_complement.htm), which is an adjective.

> My five-point plan to make Britain safe again - *Daily Telegraph*
>
> North Korea suggested today that it did not consider negotiations finished. - *New York Times*
>
> Why Things Always Go Wrong - *entrepreneur*
>
> 6 reasons why people go hungry - *global citizen*

Your sentence "he makes me happy" is an example of the CAUSE TO BE meaning of make, which requires a noun and an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

Because 'make' is a type of verb which can either take two objects or one object with one adjective.

**Example 1:** Our grandmother used to make us tea when we were children. (two objects)

**Example 2:** Police make us safe (one object and one adjective)

This is just the nature of the verb in all languages.

Comment: In all languages?

Comment: @EddieKal A brief time spent with the google finds that these verbs -- they're called *ditransitive* -- are very common, but !Xun, a language spoken in southwest Africa appears to lack this feature. Go here: https://books.google.com/books?id=8aRUkjLEGHUC&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=what+languages+have+no+ditransitive+verbs&source=bl&ots=YtxCvb7kGL&sig=ACfU3U1mlpKw9tNQ4vxktz-eFL2X88Bfew&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwib5szmirTmAhUBVc0KHdBhCEo4ChDoATAAegQICRAB#v=onepage&q=what%20languages%20have%20no%20ditransitive%20verbs&f=false

Comment: @user105719 My point is "_This is just the nature of the verb in all languages._" is way too sweeping a statement and is always decidedly wrong. I doubt anyone who says that is proficient enough **in all languages** to make such an assertion. I bet !Xun is not the only exception to this "nature of the verb". Such statements can hardly reflect anything but Eurocentric views toward human language.

Comment: @EddieKal 1) I got your point, which my comment supports. In fact, you're preaching to the choir. 2) I'm polylingual for values of *poly-* equal to *mono-*, so it would be foolish for me to take your bet. 3) It made me chuckle to hear someone criticize overly-general statements about language by claiming that only "Eurocentric views" give rise to such statements.

Comment: @user105719 Sorry didn't mean to come off as impolite. I am glad we are on the same page. Also thanks for the info. I just thought you comment was misdirected at me and would be apter as a comment to the answerer. I maintain my views on 3) :)

Comment: @EddieKal No offense taken, although that's partly because I don't have feelings, or at least none online. It's very hard to read the right tone in bare written words, and it's not unknown for commenters to be oppositional. As it turns out, the two of us are in what I call (facetiously) "violent agreement." It's hard enough to make sweeping, accurate statements about any one language. How much harder for all of them!

Answer (score 0):

*Make* is not *required* take two objects.

When you use *make* with two objects, the overall meaning is usually similar to "create X and give X to me".  Usually there is some form of "giving" with any verb that uses two objects.

> Make me a sandwich.

You can say this and be perfectly OK.

> Make a sandwich, then give it to me.

*Give* is required to have two objects.

However, there are phrasal variations of *give* which take one or zero objects, and one of those is *give up*.

> The enemy gave up. (OK).
>
> He gave up the money (OK).
>
> He completely gave up (OK).
>
> He gives me.  (Incomplete and wrong, *give* used like this needs the other object)

Interestingly, with *give up*, or another phrasal verb *give away*, you have to use *to X* if you specify who you are "giving up" or "giving away" to.

> He gave away me the money (Wrong, sounds bad).
>
> He gave away the money to me.